# Great Expectation with Azure and Databricks

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-databricks, great-expectations

I want to run great_expectation test suites against csv files in my ADLS Gen2. On my ADLS, I have a container called "input" in which I have a file at input/GE/ind.csv. I use a InferredAssetAzureDataConnector. I was able to create and test/validate the data source configuration. But when i validate my data I'm getting below error.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from ruamel import yaml

from great_expectations.core.batch import RuntimeBatchRequest
from great_expectations.data_context import BaseDataContext
from great_expectations.data_context.types.base import (
    DataContextConfig,
    FilesystemStoreBackendDefaults,
)

from ruamel import yaml
import great_expectations as ge
from great_expectations.core.batch import Batch, BatchRequest


#Root Directory
root_directory = "/dbfs/FileStore/great_expectation_official/"

#Data Context
data_context_config = DataContextConfig(
    store_backend_defaults=FilesystemStoreBackendDefaults(
        root_directory=root_directory
    ),
)
context = BaseDataContext(project_config=data_context_config)


#Configure your Datasource
datasource_config = {
    "name": "my_azure_datasource",
    "class_name": "Datasource",
    "execution_engine": {
        "class_name": "SparkDFExecutionEngine",
        "azure_options": {
            "account_url": "https://<account_Name>.blob.core.windows.net",
            "credential": "ADLS_key",
        },
    },
    "data_connectors": {
        "default_inferred_data_connector_name": {
            "class_name": "InferredAssetAzureDataConnector",
            "azure_options": {
                "account_url": "https://<account_Name>.blob.core.windows.net",
                "credential": "ADLS_key",
            },
            "container": "input",
            "name_starts_with": "/GE/",
            "default_regex": {
                "pattern": "(.*)\\.csv",
                "group_names": ["data_asset_name"],
            },
        },
    },
}

context.test_yaml_config(yaml.dump(datasource_config))

context.add_datasource(**datasource_config)

batch_request = BatchRequest(
    datasource_name="my_azure_datasource",
    data_connector_name="default_inferred_data_connector_name",
    data_asset_name="data_asset_name",
    batch_spec_passthrough={"reader_method": "csv", "reader_options": {"header": True}},
)

context.create_expectation_suite(
    expectation_suite_name="test_suite", overwrite_existing=True
)
validator = context.get_validator(
    batch_request=batch_request, expectation_suite_name="test_suite"
)
```

[Error_snapshot_click_here]

[image: 1]

[csv_data_snapshot]

[image: 2]

Can someone help me to find out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the following code whether your batch list is indeed empty.

```
context.get_batch_list(batch_request=batch_request)
```

If this is empty, you probably have an issue with your data_asset_names.
You can check whether the correct data asset name has been used in the output of the following code.

```
context.test_yaml_config(yaml.dump(my_spark_datasource_config))
```

In the output there is a list of available data_asset_names that you can choose from. If the data asset_name of your BatchRequest is not in the list, you will have an empty batch_list as the data asset is not available. There should be a warning here but I think it is not implemented.

I had the same issue but figured it out yesterday. Also, you should produce a workable example of your error so people can explore the code. That way it is easier to help you.

Hopefully this helps!